# jQuery .length() with appended elements

Tags: jquery, append

I'm having a little problem with the .length() property. I'm trying to count the number of spans in each div with a same class. Those Divs are appended previously in the script. The funny thing is, if I alert the variable corresponding to the length, everything works fine, if I remove the alert, it doesn't. Never seen that before so any help would be appreciated :) Here is the code :

```
getTweets();
tweetCounter = function(){
    $('.entry').each(function(){
        var nTweets = $('.tweet', this).length;
        var infoPane = $('.infoPane', this);
        var tLink = '<a href="#" class="tLink" title="Tweets of the day">' + nTweets + ' Tweets that day</a>'; 
        infoPane.append(tLink);
        //alert(nTweets);   
    });


}
tweetCounter();
```

As I said, it appends correctly when I uncomment the alert. If commented, 0 is displayed on every DIV... 
Any ideas ?

Here's the *getTweets* function :

```
getTweets = function(){
var url = "http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/charleshaa.json?count=30&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        var fullTDate = item.created_at;
        var splitTDate = fullTDate.split(" ");
        var tMonth = splitTDate[1];
        if (tMonth == "Jan"){
            tMonth = "01"
        } else if(tMonth == "Feb"){
            tMonth = "02"
        } else if(tMonth == "Mar"){
            tMonth = "03"
        } else if(tMonth == "Apr"){
            tMonth = "04"
        } else if(tMonth == "May"){
            tMonth = "05"
        } else if(tMonth == "Jun"){
            tMonth = "06"
        } else if(tMonth == "Jul"){
            tMonth = "07"
        } else if(tMonth == "Aug"){
            tMonth = "08"
        } else if(tMonth == "Sep"){
            tMonth = "09"
        } else if(tMonth == "Oct"){
            tMonth = "10"
        } else if(tMonth == "Nov"){
            tMonth = "11"
        } else if(tMonth == "Dec"){
            tMonth = "12"
        }
        var tDay = splitTDate[2];
        var tYear = splitTDate[5];
        var tDate = tDay + '-' + tMonth + '-' + tYear;
        var tText = '<span class="tweet">' + item.text + '</span>';
        //alert(tDate);

        var destination = $('#date_'+ tDate +'');
        destination.append(tText);

    });
});

}
```

Comment: There isn't a function such as `.length()` in jQuery. `length` is just a property of a javascript array.

Comment: @TheSuperTramp: yes there is. A jQuery object acts like an array-like-object and therefore owns a `.length` property.

Comment: That is exactly wat i was saying. You can write `$('div').length` but not `$('div').length()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment. It pretty much looks like that the function which adds the `.tweet` elements does this asyncronously (maybe an ajax-request ?) If that is the case, the method does not *block* the code execution and again, this would bring your behavior.

What you would need to do in this case is, provide a *callback* function to the function which gets and creates the tweets. If that has finished, execute the callback.

```
function get_tweets() {
    var requests = [ ];

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        requests.push( $.getJSON('/foo' + i + '.json', function(data) {
            // do something and create `.tweet` nodes
        }) );
    }

    return requests;
}

$.when.apply( null, get_tweets() ).done( count_tweets );
```

This is how it could look like in jQuery 1.5.2+. The `get_tweets()` function here fires 5 requests and stores the `Deferred` object in an array which is returned. `$.when()` will fire when all promises are fulfilled.

**update**

Here is how it should look like with 1.3.2:

```
getTweets = function( callback ){
    var url = "http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/charleshaa.json?count=30&callback=?";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            var fullTDate = item.created_at;
            var splitTDate = fullTDate.split(" ");
            // and so forth....
        });

        if( typeof callback === 'function' )
            callback();
    });
}
```

and then call it like

```
getTweets( tweetCounter );
```

Comment: That's what I thought too... The snippet is in a `.ready()` and the function that adds the `.tweet` (_getTweets();_) is right before this one. Look at my edit...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the only problem is that I can't use any jQuery newer than 1.3.2 ... Do you have any ideas on how I could do it with this version ?

Comment: Oh and why would it work if I alert the nTweets ? If I knew, maybe there could be some other function I could use without having any dialog boxes showing up :)

Comment: @Charleshaa: what a pity. With 1.3.2 you would have to to give `.getTweets()` a parameter where you can pass in a function. Within `getTweets` you need to execute that parameter(function) when you receieved the data.

Comment: Still a newbie, could you illustrate that with a snippet please ? :)

Comment: @Charleshaa: the `alert()` creates a modal dialog and freezes the code execution. At the point where you call it, the `.getTweets()` function was already executed and any asyncronous task would have enough time to finish.

Comment: @Charleshaa: please post the whole `.getTweets()` function aswell.